# Is there a way we can return to the page from where we started after the checkout in Bigcommerce?

Tags: javascript, php, bigcommerce

I don't want any code, I just want to know is there a way we can go back to the page from where we added our product in the add to cart and there is a button called 'continue shopping' and it will return to from where we clicked your add to cart.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can either build in your own logic or use one of the themes available on BigCommerce. For example, [this](https://cornerstone-light-demo.mybigcommerce.com/) theme uses a modal to keep the customer on the same page when adding to cart. This [theme](http://mogul-clean-demo.mybigcommerce.com) shows a message the product has been added to the cart while keeping the shopper on the same page. For more ideas, you can see the [BigCommerce Theme Store](https://www.bigcommerce.com/theme-store/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below...
Add below html where you want to show the continue shopping button and you're done...
**Note: This will redirect page to the homepage of your store. As there is not any default functionality for this in bigcommerce, this is a good option.**

```
<span class="extrautils-span" onclick="window.location.href=window.location.origin">Continue Shopping</span>
```